# chrome extensions Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey iam trying to build a Chrome extensions that does simply thing , like removing element 
and i get this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function)

and i know for sure that the page have jquery and also my extensions have jquery.

here is the json code:

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "jonathan",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.10.1.min.js", "alert.js","contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
   "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*" , "https://*/*"
  ],

  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

This is the HTML File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>
     <script src='alert.js'></script>
     <script src='contentscript.js'></script>

</head>


<body>

<h1 id = "title">Test</h1>

<input type = "button" value ="Find And Replace" id="btn1" />
<input type = "button" value ="Move Steps" id="btn2" />
<input type = "button" value ="Move Steps" id="btn3" />

<div id="content">


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the Js file

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {

        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            $('#content').load('index.html',function() {
                $('#changebtn').click(function(){
                    var rep = $('#replace').val();
                    var find = $('#find').val();
                    replace(find,rep);

                });
            })
        });

        $('#btn2').click(function(){
            $('#content').load('movestep.html',function() {
                $('#changebtn').click(function(){   

                });
            })
        });
    });
```

And this is the Other JS file that does the Script injection

```
function replace(Find,Replace)
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"$('#topBar').val('dfasdfasdfasdfklajsdfklasdg')"});
    console.log("Good");
}
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I created a project with the above code and the only error I'm getting is that the files "movestep.html" and "index.html" do not exist. What is supposed to be in those files? Chances are, the problem is in there somewhere.

Comment: its just an simple html file that does no think , you can do it like this:

Comment: $('#btn1').click(function(){
                   replace(find,rep)
        });

        $('#btn2').click(function(){

            })
        });

Comment: Still not getting that error. The extension doesn't really do much, but I'm not getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function)" in the console. Which console are you looking at? I'm looking at the console for the popup. When the popup shows I right click on it and choose "Inspect Element" and then choose the "Console" tab. I click on all three buttons and never see that error message. Are you sure something is not wrong with your JQuery file? Or is there some other plug in you're loading that you aren't mentioning here that could be interfering with JQuery?

Comment: Iam looking at the site console, not the extension console.

Comment: basicly iam trying to send script into site..

Comment: So you're looking at the site into which your script is being injected? I tried looking at this as well and didn't get this error message. Is there a specific site you can show me that causes this? Chances are the problem is with the site itself, because injected code is completely sandboxed and does not affect the code on a site.